# How can I get the values from a line in an array?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to get the y2 value of a line from an array but everything I try does not work.

```
var example = array.new_line() 


dx = adjX - origX
dy = adjY - origY
priceUnit = dy / dx

    // Draw line
    x1 = origX + dx * 8
        array.push(example, line.new(origX, origY, x1, adjY, extend=extend.right, color=#64B5F6, width=1)
    //list of other lines being pushed

    for i = 0 to example.size() - 1
         yline = array.get(example,i).get_y2()  //tried this
         ylineb = array.get(myLines, 0) // tried this together with ylineb[1]
         ylinec = example.get_y2() // tried this in various ways
         
//I tried a few other ways but I never get any y values from the line.
```

I am expecting to get the value of y2 but I get nothing but errors. The array is not empty since it draws everything the way it is supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use `line.get_y2()` See example below, the label will plot the y2 value of the line which is set to the current bars close.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)

var lineArr = array.new<line>()

if barstate.islast
    lineArr.unshift(line.new(bar_index[49], low[49], bar_index, close))

y = lineArr.size() > 0 ? line.get_y2(lineArr.get(0)) : na

if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index,high, str.tostring(y), textcolor=color.white)
```